# Installing only what I need for Slackware on VMware Player

Tags: linux, vmware, slackware

I am trying to install Slackware 14 on VMware using as little space as possible but still be able to access any features I need.  I do okay until I get to the part where it asks for the packages I want to install, I don't know what some these packages are or whether or not I really need them.

One thing I wanted to try was install Slackware with a minimal desktop environment, but I am not sure if the main things that I would like to do would be available to me if I did this: programming (python), web surfing, and maybe a small game or two.  I mostly need a linux virtual machine for programming with the ability to surf the web without having to constantly switch in and out of VMware/windows.

Here are the package series' the selection gives me with premade selections ([*] means the series is currently selected):
[image: first half of selection list]
[image: second half of selection list]

How much can I take out and still do the things mentioned before the list?
I took out the KDE and XFCE desktop environments would I still be able to work on programming projects, web surf, and/or play a small game?

Comment: Why not install just the base, and build it up as you need it?

Answer (score 1):

Are you concerned about disk-space, or performance?

You can happily get rid of TeX if you're not into type-setting, and there's lots of stuff in libraries, networking and so forth you probably won't need.

But it would be safer to go with a full install, and then trim out things you know you won't need; bear in mind that there's no dependency checks with package-tools, so it won't stop you from stuffing up either way.